# Is my simple one-line Nginx to Tomcat configuration okay?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tomcat

This is short question, but I'm including all the details below for clarity.

Short version: Is there anything wrong or bad about my nginx to tomcat configuration which is one line instead of the more complex way the tutorials said to do it?

**MY CONFIG:**

Ubuntu instance on AWS.  I installed Tomcat, I can see my app at: http://myserver:8080/myapp

Then I installed Nginx.

I configured Nginx by editing the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file and adding the `location /myapp { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp; }` section to the file, like so ...

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # ... commented out stuff ...

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /myapp {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp;
        }

}
```

Restarted nginx and it works!  I can see my app at: http://myserver/myapp

**THE TUTORIALS CONFIG:**

When I look at tutorials like [HERE](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-setup-tomcat-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and [HERE](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-nginx-proxy-server-for-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/) and [HERE](https://mkyong.com/nginx/nginx-apache-tomcat-configuration-example/), they all have more complicated steps.

They say to create a separate file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf` and put a configuration like this in it ...

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name    example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

And then create a symbolic link like so ...

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
systemctl restart nginx
```

I actually tried it their way and it didn't work for me for some reason ... and then I stumbled on my simple solution.

MY QUESTION IS ... is there anything wrong or bad about the way I did it by just adding that one line?  I want to make sure I'm doing things correctly.